# What does -1.#IND mean for real variables in vhdl simulation

Tags: vhdl

[image: vhdl simulation]

We are writing a code in vhdl. yr22 and yi22 are signals. We are not getting what -1.#IND means.

Heres the code for reference.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_signed.all;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity lms2 is
    Port (wr9,wi9,xr,xi : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0);
           --u : in integer;

           yr,yi,er,ei,wr8,wi8,zzz,sum1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (12 downto 0));
end lms2;

architecture Behavioral of lms2 is
signal a,b :real;
signal yr11, yi11, yr22, yi22 : real;
signal p1,p2,p3,p4 :real;
signal q1,q2,q3,q4 :real;
signal r1,r2,r3,r4 :real;
signal s1,s2,s3,s4 :real;

--variable r,s : real range 0.0 to 15.0;

begin

process(wr9,wi9,xr,xi)--process also runs without the parameters,but it gives problems during simulation
--process(u,xr,xi)
variable wr : std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
variable wi : std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);

--variable wr : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :="00010";
--variable wi : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :="00011";
--variable wr : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :=wr9;
--variable wi : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :=wi9;
variable xr1_1 : real;
variable xi1_1 : real;

variable xr1_2 : real;
variable xi1_2 : real;

variable xr_0 : real :=0.707;
variable xi_0 : real :=0.701;

variable xr_1 : real :=0.704;
variable xi_1 : real :=0.703;

variable xr_2 : real :=0.705;
variable xi_2 : real :=0.709;

variable xr_3 : real :=0.701;
variable xi_3 : real :=0.704;

variable dr1 : real :=0.807;
variable di1 : real :=0.801;
variable yr1_1: real;
variable yi1_1 : real;
variable yr1_2 : real;
variable yi1_2 : real;

variable er1_1 : real;
variable ei1_1 : real;
variable er1_2 : real;
variable ei1_2 : real;

variable wr1_1 : real := 0.0;
variable wi1_1 : real := 0.0;

variable wr1_2 : real := 0.0;
variable wi1_2 : real := 0.0;

variable u   : real :=0.008;
variable k : integer :=0;

variable f : real := 3.2;
variable g : real := 2.6;
variable h : real;
variable hh : real;


begin

h := f+g;
hh := f*g;
a <= h;
b <=hh;

--process(xr,xi,u)
--bi <= to_integer(unsigned(k)) ;
--bj <= to_integer(unsigned(l)) ;
--bk <= bi*bj;





for z in 1 to 100 loop
if (k=0)then
xr1_1 := xr_0;
xi1_1 := xi_0;
xr1_2 := xr_3;
xr1_2 := xi_3;

elsif (k=1) then
xr1_1 := xr_1;
xi1_1 := xi_1;
xr1_2 := xr_0;
xr1_2 := xi_0;

elsif (k=2) then
xr1_1 := xr_2;
xi1_1 := xi_2;
xr1_2 := xr_1;
xr1_2 := xi_1;

elsif (k=3) then
xr1_1 := xr_3;
xi1_1 := xi_3;
xr1_2 := xr_2;
xr1_2 := xi_2;
end if;
k := k+1;
if(k=4) then
k := 0;
end if;
yr1_1 := wr1_1*xr1_1-wi1_1*xi1_1;
yi1_1 := wr1_1*xi1_1+wi1_1*xr1_1;
yr1_2 := wr1_2*xr1_2-wi1_2*xi1_2;
yi1_2 := wr1_2*xi1_2+wi1_2*xr1_2;

er1_1 := (wr1_1*xr1_1)-(wi1_1*xi1_1)-dr1;
ei1_1 := (wr1_1*xi1_1)+(wi1_1*xr1_1)-di1;
er1_2 := (wr1_2*xr1_2)-(wi1_2*xi1_2)-dr1;
ei1_2 := (wr1_2*xi1_2)+(wi1_2*xr1_2)-di1;

if (er1_1<0.0) then
er1_1 := (-1.0)*er1_1;
end if;

if (ei1_1<0.0) then
ei1_1 := (-1.0)*ei1_1;
end if;

if (er1_2<0.0) then
er1_2 := (-1.0)*er1_2;
end if;

if (ei1_2<0.0) then
ei1_2 := (-1.0)*ei1_2;
end if;

if(z=1) then
p1<=er1_1;
p2<=ei1_1;
p3<=er1_2;
p4<=ei1_2;
end if;

if(z=25) then
q1<=er1_1;
q2<=ei1_1;
q3<=er1_2;
q4<=ei1_2;
end if;

if(z=50) then
r1<=er1_1;
r2<=ei1_1;
r3<=er1_2;
r4<=ei1_2;
end if;

if(z=100) then
s1<=er1_1;
s2<=ei1_1;
s3<=er1_2;
s4<=ei1_2;
end if;

wr1_1 := u*(xr1_1*er1_1-xi1_1*ei1_1)+wr1_1;
wi1_1 := u*(xr1_1*ei1_1+xi1_1*er1_1)+wi1_1;
wr1_2 := u*(xr1_2*er1_2-xi1_2*ei1_2)+wr1_2;
wi1_2 := u*(xr1_2*ei1_2+xi1_2*er1_2)+wi1_2;



end loop;

yr11 <= yr1_1;
yi11 <= yi1_1;
yr22 <= yr1_2;
yi22 <= yi1_2;

end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: It is how windows outputs certain non numeric floating point states

Comment: But yr22 and yi22 holds numeric data(real in this case). yr22 and yi22 are expected to hold values like that of yr11 and yi11. How can they be non numeric.

Comment: do you seriously expect anyone to know the answer by not having anything more than the screenshot?

Comment: ok i am posting the code

Comment: Look at the values of all the terms used to generate these values. Either some of them are incorrect, or you are combining them with incorrect logic. Fix whatever problems you find and repeat until you get valid values. Test with inputs that generate a known output, and verify that you actually get that output. Oh, and delete that non-standard `std_logic_signed` library so you know you're only using `numeric_std`.

Comment: The code doesn't use package numeric_std either. See [What do 1.#INF00, -1.#IND00 and -1.#IND mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347920/what-do-1-inf00-1-ind00-and-1-ind-mean)